# Unable to generate signed apk due to lint errors

Tags: android, build.gradle, apk, lint

I am having trouble in generating signed apk. Lint errors displayed on screen
Following error shows 
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0. Examples include 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0' and 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0'

Dependencies in build.gradle file is below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    //picasso libraray
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //retrofit libraries

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
}
```

On this line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

lint error occurred

Answer (score 1):

> AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in
>   the androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names
>   changed; class, method, and field names did not change.

Read official guideline about - Migrating to [**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). You should migrate to AndroidX.

> With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing
>   project to AndroidX by selecting ***Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX*** from
>   the menu bar.

**`dependencies`** will be

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Then add below in your **`build.gradle`** section.

```
 android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is preventing other errors that might happen when the app is running. You are asking to skip error at build time at runtime app may behave weirdly.